# How to have JSDoc style comments autocomplete in sass files in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, jsdoc

I use JSDoc syntax to document a lot of parts throughout all my apps.

I often need to make some minimal documentation for SASS variables as well.

However, while any JS/TS/Vue file works really well with JSDoc style comment blocks in VSCode, Sass files seem to try and work against me when trying to type a JSDoc comment...

I know it's possible by just adding some sort of snippet that expands into a JSDoc comment block, but the problem is when pressing ENTER, in JS/TS/Vue files it automatically adds the proper indentation and `*` in front of the new line inside the comments.

In Sass files, not only is the indentation is consistently wrong when pressing ENTER in a comment block and it's not helping me at all by adding `*` or the closing `*/` tag...

I have looked all over the extensions of VSCode as well, but couldn't find anything that helped.

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

[image: Sass JSDoc problems]